# Unexpected error ( table doesn't exist ) when run migration in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have many migration to migrate and my database is empty now.

When i run `php artisan migrate` i got this error :

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shop.permissions' doesn't 
exist")
```

And this is my permissions migration :

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permission_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'user_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
        $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['permission_id', 'role_id']);
    });

    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);
    });
```

When i create permissions manual in my database and run `php artisan migrate` it work without this error but after some migration i got this error :

```
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permissions' already exists
```

What can i do to migrate my tables ??

Comment: sounds like you have a service provider that is making a query to gather permissions for some reason ... when the database is empty there isn't a table for it to query

Comment: exactly, i have a query in my AuthServiceProvider and i comment that and run migration, its work, thank, put your comment in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times this is an issue that comes up when you have a Service Provider querying for permissions, often to setup gates for authorization. The Service Providers are booted every time the application is booted which includes in the console. When the database is empty there is no table to query.

If you are doing this query for the purpose of authorization, you may not need to be doing this when running in the console since there is no web request coming in. If you would like you can try making what ever you are doing conditional to try and not run if running in the console; in the Service Provider:

```
if (! $this->app->runningInConsole()) {
    // not running in console
}
```